# Hpw to display pdf in webpage without download, print and save option using jsp and pdf.js?

Tags: javascript, java, jsp

I want to display pdf file in webpage without allowing user to download, save and print.

Comment: What do you want to reach? I don't think this is possible, because if it's displayed in the browser it can be downloaded as well.

Comment: @ sinclair, thanks for comment. I want to open file in browser in read only mode.

Comment: Short: Not possible. Long: You can make it more difficult for user to get the information, but if it has to be displayed, it can be always downloaded/printed - at least as the series of screenshots.